# MP4 Video not playing on Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview, android-virtual-device

I have a videoView in which I want to display an MP4 video from a URL. I tried it on Andoird 4.0.2 emulator and it worked fine. However, on trying it on A GingerBread hardware, it crashed.  I also tried it on Gingerbread emulator, thinking there could be something wrong with my device, but still no progress. The logcat is repeating these again and again when I tap the Play button.

`04-11 23:49:27.438: V/VideoViewDemo(413): path: http://173.193.24.66/~kanz/video/mp4/9.mp4
04-11 23:49:28.796: D/MediaPlayer(413): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-11 23:49:38.207: D/MediaPlayer(413): getMetadata
04-11 23:49:39.343: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (701, 0)
04-11 23:49:39.346: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (701,0)
04-11 23:49:45.556: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (702, 0)
04-11 23:49:45.556: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (702,0)
04-11 23:51:11.467: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (701, 0)
04-11 23:51:11.467: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (701,0)
04-11 23:51:22.096: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (702, 0)
04-11 23:51:22.096: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (702,0)
04-11 23:51:25.636: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (701, 0)
04-11 23:51:25.636: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (701,0)
04-11 23:51:37.127: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (702, 0)
04-11 23:51:37.127: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (702,0)
04-11 23:51:41.717: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (701, 0)
04-11 23:51:41.717: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (701,0)
04-11 23:51:54.086: W/MediaPlayer(413): info/warning (702, 0)
04-11 23:51:54.097: I/MediaPlayer(413): Info (702,0)`

It isn't showing any error so that I can know which line is exactly causing the problem. Here's the Play button's code:

```
try {
        final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {


                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://173.193.24.66/~kanz/video/mp4/9.mp4"));

                mVideoView.requestFocus();

                mVideoView.start();
                return;
            }
             current = path;

            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getDataSource(path)));


            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.start();


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this code,

```
String videoSource = "http://173.193.24.66/~kanz/video/mp4/9.mp4";

myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    myVideoView.start();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying this from emulator or from real phone?